# Chern class of a hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}P^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, curvature, projective-space, complex-manifolds

Let $X=\{[z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3]\ \big{|}\ [z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3]\in\mathbb{C}P^3,z_0^4+z_1^4+z_2^4+z_3^4=0\}$. $c_1(X)$ is the first Chern class of $X$. Prove that $c_1(X)=0$.

$\textbf{My try}$:

It's easy to show that $X$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{C}P^3$. Let $D$ be a connection on $X$. $\Theta=D\circ D$ is a curvature. Then $c_1(X)=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi}tr(\Theta)$. So I need to prove that $tr(\Theta)=0$. Let $h$ be the Hermitian metric. $X_0=\{[z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3]\ \big{|}\ [z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3]\in X,z_0\ne 0\}\ $. On $X_0\ $ $h([z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3])=1+\frac{|z_1|^2}{|z_0|^2}+\frac{|z_2|^2}{|z_0|^2}+\frac{|z_3|^2}{|z_0|^2}=1+\xi_1^2+\xi_2^2+\xi_3^2$. Let $D$ be the Chern connection. Then $\Theta=d\theta\ $ where $\theta=h^{-1}\partial h$. On $X_0$, $\xi_1^4+\xi_2^4+\xi_3^4=-1$. But I can't cauculate $tr(\Theta)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know the adjunction formula?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, Sorry, I don't know. How to use it to solve my problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_formula#Degree_d_hypersurfaces

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, Okay. But I still don't know the relation between first Chern class and adjunction formula. I know little about algebra geometry.

Comment: How to solve it using the tools of complex geometry?

Comment: Work with the normal bundle $N$. But eventually you're going to need to know that $c_1(X) = c_1(\Bbb P^3)-c_1(N)$ and that $c_1(\Bbb P^3) = 4\omega$, where $\omega$ is the (normalized) Kähler form.

Comment: @TedShifrin, How to calculate $c_1(N)$?

Comment: You need to work with transition functions to see that the normal bundle of a hypersurface $X$ of degree $d$ is $\mathscr O_X(d)$. One way to see this is that if $X$ is given by $f_i$ on $U_i$, then on $U_i\cap U_j$ we have $df_i = (f_i/f_j)df_j$, and $df_i$ gives a section of $N^*$ on $U_i$.

Comment: By the way, you have a misconception in your post. You do not need to show that the $2$-form $\text{tr}(\Theta)$ is $0$. You need to show its cohomology class is $0$.